# How to set position?

Tags: java, position

I am written this code:

```
if (_position == 0) {
linear2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
linear3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
linear1.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(getApplicationContext()) {
        
    public void onSwipeRight() {
        Set position = 1;
    }
    
});
```

The problem is in  Set position = 1;
It shows error : `Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to Set`
How can i fix this or write the code in another way so it changes the position to 1 instead of 0 when the user swipe?

Comment: `Set position` could never be a method call to change a position, that defines a variable named `position` of type `Set` , do yoy get that ?

Comment: I‘m not quite sure what you‘re trying to do, but Set is a data type. You‘re currently declaring a variable of type set and assign an integer to it, which doesn‘t make much sense to me.

Comment: I want to change the position of selected tab on sketchware

Answer (score 0):

When you write `Set position = 1;` you are declaring a java.util.Set (a collection of unique values) and assign it the value 1 (an integer number). Java thinks this doesn't make sense.

If you are trying to set something, don't use a java.util.Set, but call one of the methods with a name starting with `set` like `setPosition(int pos);`.

If you want to update the value of the `_position` variable shown, then just assign it a new value: `_position = 1`